# How to combine graphics and text (paragraphs, tables) on one page using itextsharp?

Tags: itext

I am working on generating a PDF report using itextsharp. The format of the report roughly is like this:
Some text (paragraph), followed by a table, followed by a graph, followed by another table.
I used PdfPTable to draw tables, Paragraph to write a text, and PdfContentByte to draw a graph. 
The issue is, the second table is not positioned properly i.e. it is not drawn after the graphics. 
I guess the issue is I am trying to combine a higher level (using Document object) with lower level (Using direct content) operation.
Can anyone please help me to find a better solution for my problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `Paragraph` and the `PdfPTable` are high-level objects. What you do with `PdfContentByte` are low-level operations. You're mixing the high-level approach with the low-level approach in the wrong way.

You need to create a `PdfTemplate` object (see the CreatTemplate method in `PdfContentByte`) and draw the graphics to that `PdfTemplate` object; think of it as a small, reusable rectangular canvas.

Once you're done, you can wrap the `PdfTemplate` inside an `Image` object. Don't worry: it won't be rasterized; it will remain a vector-based graphical object. Once you have that Image, you can continue using `Document.Add()` and the low-level operations wont overlap with the high-level objects.

Comment: Hi Bruno,Thanks for the reply. I did something similar. I first created graphics using System.Drawing then I converted it to an image and I added that image using Document.Add(). But I would try your method too.